# Choose JDBC database depends on logged user

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ldap, spring-security-ldap

I have a simple spring boot application. I am using JDBC connection configured by JDBC Template (JDBC url is got from properties file).
Can you tell me how to reach following thing:
JDBC Connection should be established in depends on logged user, I have a problem with projecting in spring such flow of control that object jdbc template will be created  after loggining user.
It is about different users use different database.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: https://www.infoq.com/articles/Multiple-Databases-with-Spring-Boot

Answer (score 0):

You can do the routing at the datasource level.

See https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/

And

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html